# AMD Graphics card not being recognised in ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS

Tags: drivers, 20.04, amd-graphics

when trying to find which graphics card is installed on my ubuntu system I have found that there is no graphics card detected.
there is no output from lspci or lshw
for example,
`lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'`
returns nothing

any help is greatly appreciated,
thanks

edit:
`lspci` output:

````
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 03)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-V USB Controller
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-V Thermal Subsystem
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-V HECI Controller
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 400 Series Chipset Family SATA AHCI Controller
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #21 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #05 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port 9 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation B460 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Memory controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-V cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-V SMBus Host Controller
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)```
````

Comment: Please add output of `lspci` to your question. "vga" is not always there.

Comment: I have added the output of lspci @Pilot6

Comment: What kind of AMD Graphics is installed?

Comment: Your output is incomplete.

Comment: I have a amd radeon R9 280x installed

Comment: It is really weird that it is not shown.

Comment: yes it is very strange, especially since I only bought the graphics card is the PC wouldnt boot headless without it, so the graphics card must be working otherwise the system wouldn't boot

Answer (score 2):

The proper command to list all GPUs is

```
lspci -knn | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
```

VGA is not always there ;-)

Comment: I have tried running this command as you reccomend yet there is still nothing returned